# CSS3 gradient looks different in browsers

Tags: css, gradient

CSS3 gradient displays with different saturation in diffeent browsers. How to fix this problem? Couldn't find anything helpful.
http://d.pr/i/chm1

Here's the code:

**html**

```
<div class="button-body">
    <a href="/" class="text">Купить</a>     
</div>
```

**css**

```
.text{
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #913944;

margin-top: 7px;
margin-left: 70px;
float: left;
text-align: center;

text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 0px 1px 0.5px;

border-radius: 8px;
} 

.button-body{
height:40px;
width:200px;
display:inline-block;

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff4d55, #cc1d31);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
                color-stop(0%,#ff4d55), color-stop(100%,#cc1d31));
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff4d55, #cc1d31);

border-radius: 10px;
border: 2px solid #993f49;

box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1); 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the browsers' way of rendering are different. Using image is the best way to make it similar.

Comment: If they insist on it looking identical, then you're right. But the real solution is not to be over-sensitive to browser differences. Yes, it needs to make sure it looks good in all browsers, but if you're trying to make it look 100% the same everywhere, you're asking for trouble, and locking yourself out of using features that aren't supported on all browsers. Also, bear in mind that browsers do in fact render images differently too, so even that may not be a perfect solution.

Comment: I admit it's not a perfect solution. I wonder who can give the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Achieving identical presentation across browsers is an enormous challenge at times.  From a business perspective, you should ask yourself whether the requirements are that the elements **look identical** in all browsers or simply **look good** in all browsers.

Comment: I agree, in my works I need the designs just look good and correctly, but now I make one small research and this problem was unclear to me, wanted to be sure in my conclusions.